# Mockito test to throw RuntimeException on 3rd call to a void method

Tags: java, mockito

**UPDATED QUESTION TO CLARIFY**

I have a class with a void method.  This method will call a service which will lock user after X failed attempts to unlock a door.

Here are my classes:

```java
@Stateless(name = "DoorServiceEjb")
public class DoorServiceEjb {
    private static final int EXPIRY_PERIOD = 1;
    private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3;

    private LoadingCache<String, Integer> attemptsCache;

    public DoorServiceEjb() {
        super();
        attemptsCache = CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(EXPIRY_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, Integer>() {
                       @Override
                       public Integer load(String key) throws Exception {
                           return 0;
                       }
                   }
            );
    }

    public boolean isLockedOut(String key) {
        try {
            boolean returnValue = attemptsCache.get(key) >= MAX_ATTEMPTS;
            return  returnValue;
        }catch (ExecutionException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Door {

    @EJB(beanName = "DoorServiceEjb")
    private DoorServiceEjb doorServiceEjb;

    public void unlock(String user) {
        if (doorServiceEjb.isLockedOut(user)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Locked");
        }

        // Do something else
    }
}
```

I am expecting that `unlock()` method to throw RuntimeException if user attempts to call it with invalid username 3 or more times.

**MY QUESTIONABLE SOLUTION**

Here is my solution to test but I am not sure if this is correct.  I was always under impression that asserts and verifications are called always against @InjectMock objects (called subject under test) whereas @Mock objects are just used to mock internal dependencies inside @InjectMock object (basically, they are used to help test setup and run).
My solution, on the contrary, does not use @InjectMock at all and does verify and assert against @Mock object.

And finally, it still fails because last assert fails.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class DoorTest {

    @Mock
    private Door door;

    @Test
    public void test_3FailedUnlockAttempts_ShouldLock() {

        Mockito.doNothing().doNothing().doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(door).unlock(anyString());

        door.unlock(anyString());
        door.unlock(anyString());

        RuntimeException exception = assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> {
            door.unlock(anyString()); // should throw RuntimeException
        });

        Mockito.verify(door, times(3)).unlock(anyString());
        
   //this fails, the exception message is null rather than "Unlocked"
  Assertions.assertTrue(exception.getMessage().contains("Locked"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace.

Comment: Is that the exact error, and the exact code?  Your code appears to call the stubbed method 3 times, not 6.  Your `verify` indicates that you're expecting 3 calls, not 5.  What aren't you showing us?

Comment: The `chain` variable is not declared inside the method - are you certain it isn't used elsewhere?

Comment: Also, what on earth is `myServiceEng`?  You can't do `when` on a mock, then a whole lot of other Mockito-ish stuff, and the `thenReturn` later.  Mockito's not designed to cope with that.

Comment: I doubt that the code presented is the code causing the exception. I see nothing that indicates a wanted-count of 5. As @tgdavies said: please [edit] the post and add the stack trace. Also, please ensure that the code is compiled.

Comment: I updated the question to simplify and provide more detail.  I think the confusion comes from my limited understanding of Mockito.  I am used to AAA pattern where (to my remembering) mock is used to help test run, whereas sut (subject under test) is what you do asserts against.  But it looks like with Mockito, you simply use mocks to do both.  Anyways, regardless, I modify the question, thank you

Comment: Mocks don't "test" anything. They stand in for services/components that the code being tested uses to simulate behaviours of those services/components needed for the test.